# Boundedness of a complex polynomial outside the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $P(z)$ is a holomorphic polynomial of degree $n$ bounded above by some constant $M$ whenever $|z| = 1$. Show that $$|P(z)| \leq M|z|^n$$ whenever $|z| \geq 1$.

I ran across this problem the other day, and can't seem to solve it. Maybe some version of Schwarz's lemma combined with the Maximum Modulus Principle does the trick? I need to prove this result in order to prove a larger result for a project I am working on, but can't seem to get a good start on it. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider z^n*P(1/z) and apply the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: So, we would like to show this is constant, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $|z|\leq 1$. The function $z^nP(1/z)$ is holomorphic in the disc $|z|\leq 1$ (the pole given by the polynomial is cancelled by the $z^n$). It has to reach its maximum on the boundary $|z|=1$, hence for $|z|\leq 1$, $$|z^nP(1/z)|=|z|^n|P(1/z)|\leq \max_{|z|\leq 1}|z|^n|P(1/z)|=\max_{|z|=1}|P(1/z)|\leq M.$$

Now, let $w$ be so that $|w|\geq 1$, and pic $z=1/w$ inside the unit disc. From above we have 
$$
|w|^{-n}|P(w)|=|z^nP(1/z)|\leq M .$$ This yields the conclusion.

Comment: Once we have established the fact that we have our maximum on the boundary, where do we use that fact?

Comment: Since the maximum is on the boundary, it has to be bounded by $M$. Hence the first inequality written above actually holds for all $z$ inside the disc. Let me fix that.